# If $E[X]=0$ then $E[|X|]$ is finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I read a textbook and it says: $E[X]=0$ implies $E[|X|]<\infty$ but I cannot understand the logic. Could anyone tell me why so? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition: $E[X]$ is only defined (EDIT: as a real number) for $X$ such that $E[|X|] < \infty$.

Comment: Isn't possible to have $X = |X|$ and $E[|X|] = \infty$ ?

Comment: The Lebesgue integral is usually defined first for positive random variables $X$ (satisfying $|X| = X$) and in this case you can allow functions and integrals taking values in $[0, \infty]$. A general random variable $X$ can be decomposed into positive and negative parts: $X = X_+ - X_-$. We can then define $\int X = \int X_+ - \int X_-$ as long as we don't have $\int X_+ = \int X_- = \infty$. If only one of these integrals is infinite, it is reasonable to set $\int X = \pm \infty$. The condition that both integrals be finite is equivalent to $\int |X| < \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Well, consider a tempting example where not requiring $E[|X|]$ to be finite causes problems. Consider a variable with probability density function of $\frac{1}2\frac{1}{(|x|+1)^2}$. If we integrate 
$$\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-L}^{L}x\cdot \frac{1}2\frac{1}{(|x|+1)^2}\,dx$$
then we get $0$ as the expectation of $x$. However, if we take the limit in a different manner, say as
$$\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-2L}^{L}x\cdot \frac{1}2\frac{1}{(|x|+1)^2}\,dx$$
then we get $-\log(2)$ as the expectation - which is bad because we should've gotten the same answer!

Essentially, if we wish to make any sense of the statement $E[X]$ it is necessary to take a certain infinite integral in a well-defined sense - and this can only happen if at least one of $E[\max(x,0)]$ and $E[\min(x,0)]$ are finite. If one is infinite then $E[X]$ would also be, so if $E[X]=0$ is finite, so are both of those integrals meaning $E[|X|]$ is finite.

Comment: Why not define expectation as Cauchy principal value of the integral?

Comment: Shouldn't there be differentials in the integrals?

Comment: @A.S. Because we lose e.g. change-of-variables formulas (Law of the Unconscious Statistician).

Comment: @rubik Oh yeah. I always forget those. Fixed.

Comment: @A.S. To make explicit what Robert Israel is saying, consider a variable $X$ distributed according to: $$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}2\frac{1}{x^2+1}&&\text{if }x\geq 0 \\ \frac{1}{(2x+1)^2}&&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$ which is just the example I used in my post, with the negative end scaled by $\frac{1}2$. Then consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&&\text{if }x>0\\ 2x&&\text{if }x\leq 0\end{cases}.$$ Then $f(X)$ is just the variable I defined in my post, with expectation $0$ according to you. But then $E(f(X))=0\neq \lim_{L\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)g(x)\, dx=-\log(2)$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't apply change of variables to the limits of integration on the right as I'm not saying interpret *any* integral as PV. I am saying why not $E(X)=\lim_{T\to\infty} E(X;|X|<T)$ and become conscious when applying LOTUS? We'd lose SLLN for this definition and the only thing I can think of as a gain is Feller's WLLN (that is if $tP(|X|>t)\to 0$) - but in those cases, the updated definition would reflect a general sense that long-term average converges to PV in probability, so PV is indeed some kind of an "expected value" for certain class of rvs.

Comment: There is a good related discussion on stats.SE in the context of the Cauchy distribution: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/why-does-the-cauchy-distribution-have-no-mean.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X^+=\max\{X,0\}$ and $X^-=\max\{-X,0\}$. Then $E(X)$ is **defined** as $E(X^+)-E(X^-)$ when at least one of $E(X^+)$ and $E(X^+)$ is finite. The statement $E(X)=0$ (or $E(X)=$ any finite real number) then implicitly implies that **both** $E(X^+)$ and $E(X^+)$ are finite. We infer $E(|X|)=E(X^+)+E(X^-)$ is also finite.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
EX&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}xf(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx\\
&=A+B
\end{align}
$A+B=0$ implies $A=-B$. Note also that both $A$ and $B$ are finite.
\begin{align}
E|X|&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|f(x)dx\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^{0}xf(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx\\
&=-A+B\\
&=2B
\end{align}

Comment: This only works when $X$ has a density.

Comment: It works as well if $f(x) \; dx $ is replaced by a probability measure $d\mu$.

Comment: @Hetebrij I agree. I thought this is more understandable to the OP, nevertheless, as Robert mentioned one can get around the problems you pointed at.

Comment: @RobertIsrael many thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose on the contrary that $0 = E[X]$, but $\infty = E[|X|]$. Then, we have

$$\infty = E[|X|] = E[X^+ + X^-] = E[X^+] + E[X^-]$$

$$\to E[X^+] = \infty \ \text{or} \ E[X^-] = \infty$$

Then

$$E[X] = E[X^+ - X^-] = E[X^+] - E[X^-]$$

1. $$= \infty \ \text{if} \ E[X^+] = \infty \ \text{but} \ E[X^-] < \infty$$
2. $$= -\infty \ \text{if} \ E[X^-] = \infty \ \text{but} \ E[X^+] < \infty$$
3. $$\text{is indeterminate otherwise}$$

All cases contradict $E[X] = 0$, or any other real number for that matter. This is why in the first place using '$E[X]$' often requires that $E[|X|] = \infty$. Exceptions include when the random variable takes values in $(\overline{\mathbb R}, \mathscr B(\overline{\mathbb R}))$